# In Javascript, is typeof var !== undefined equivalent to if(var)

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is:

```
if(typeof p_options.data_type !== "undefined") { }
```

Absolutely equivalent to just doing:

```
if(p_options.data_type) { }
```

Are there any edge cases or gotchas?

Comment: typeof prevents what would otherwise be a ref error. if you have a known object like p_options, and you expect data_type to never be 0 or false, then yeah, they produce the same behavior in the code shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**. It definitely is not the same.

Imagine if `p_options.data_type` was `false`, `0`, `""`, or any other ["falsey"](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) value. This is very different from `undefined`.

```
p_options.data_type = false;

console.log(typeof p_options.data_type !== "undefined"); // true
console.log(p_options.data_type);                        // false
```